# Asymetric curly braces TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

How can I draw asymetric curly braces in `TikZ`? I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
>=stealth,]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt}]
(0,2)--(0,0) node[midway, right, font=\footnotesize, xshift=2pt] {Compromise loss};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

But how can I have for instance 1/3 length below the "beak" and 2/3 length above?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to draw an unbalanced curly brace in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110907) I guess?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Unbalanced/asymetric - Jeje! My mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `aspect` key to change the position of the beak.

Modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
>=stealth,]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,aspect=0.67}]
(0,2)--(0,0) node[pos=0.67, right, font=\footnotesize, xshift=2pt] {Compromise loss};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]