# How to overbrace / underbrace in text mode (using TikZ?)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create something
 that somewhat looks like this:

[image]

I know about `\overbrace` but that only applies to math mode. I couldn't find an `\overbrace` for text. And while I probably could use math mode, it somehow feels wrong to do so.

I tried TikZ as suggested in a [few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/adding-underbrace-in-tikz) [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/draw-curly-braces-in-tikz) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/how-to-draw-an-unbalanced-curly-brace-in-tikz) and I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{figure}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}

\tikzmark{begin}%
http:
\tikzmark{schema}
//user:password@domain.com:port/resource
\tikzmark{query}
?query=foo
\tikzmark{fragment}
\#fragment
\tikzmark{end}

\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5mm,amplitude=24pt}] (begin.north west) -- node [above=16mm] {URI} (end.north east) ;
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=24pt,mirror}] (schema.south west) -- node[below of=begin, below=6mm] {Schema} (end.south east) ;
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (fragment.south west) -- node[below of=begin, below=6mm] {Fragment} (end.south east) ;
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

While that looks like it has potential: [image: rendered code]  it feels awkward having to manually adjust the position of the labels with `above=6mm` and `below`.

So I *guess* I want to not care about the exact positions and do it roughly like this:

```
\overbrace{URI}{\underbrace{schema}{http:}\underbrace{specific}{//\underbrace{credentials}{user:pass}}}
```

Comment: You can do `$\underbrace{\text{\#fragment}}_{\text{Fragment}$` in [tag:math-mode] with the `amsmath` package.

Comment: This can be done with ease using `\overbrace`/`\underbrace`. Are you tied to [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a `matrix` of `node`s and then making use of the corners of those nodes (via `.north west`, `.north east`, `.south west`, and `.south east`) for `\draw`ing the paths, combined with the ability to set `node`s along paths, allows you to do this in `TikZ`. Moreover, you can use `\tikzstyle` to set some of the options globally, so you don't have to manually adjust the position of the labels continually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{overbrace text style}=[font=\tiny, above, pos=.5, yshift=3mm]
\tikzstyle{overbrace style}=[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=3pt}]
\tikzstyle{underbrace style}=[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=3pt,mirror},color=gray]
\tikzstyle{underbrace text style}=[font=\tiny, below, pos=.5, yshift=-3mm]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[name=M1, matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, column sep=0pt]{
      \node (schema) [text=red] {http:\vphantom{/}}; & \node (schema-spezifisch) [text=black] {//}; & \node (nutzerinfo) [text=orange] {user:pass\vphantom{/}}; & @ & \node (host) [text=blue] {www.example.com\vphantom{/}}; & : & \node (port) [text=blue!40] {1234\vphantom{/}}; & \node (pfad) [text=red] {/directory/index.php}; & \node (query) [text=purple] {?key=value\vphantom{/}}; & \node (fragment) [text=green] {\#anchor\vphantom{/}};  \\
    };

    \draw [overbrace style] (schema.north west) -- (schema.north east) node [overbrace text style] {Schema};
    \draw [overbrace style] (schema-spezifisch.north west) -- (fragment.north east) node [overbrace text style] {Schema-Spezifisch};
    \draw [underbrace style] (nutzerinfo.south west) -- (nutzerinfo.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=orange] {Nutzerinfo};
    \draw [underbrace style] (host.south west) -- (host.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=blue] {Host};
    \draw [underbrace style] (port.south west) -- (port.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=blue!40,baseline] {Port};
    \draw [underbrace style] (pfad.south west) -- (pfad.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=red] {Pfad};
    \draw [underbrace style] (query.south west) -- (query.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=purple] {Query};
    \draw [underbrace style] (fragment.south west) -- (fragment.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=green] {Fragment};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[name=M2, matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, column sep=0pt]{
      \node (URI) {http:}; & \node (schema) [text=black] {//user:password@domain.com:port/resource?query=foo}; & \node (fragment) {\#fragment};  \\
    };

    \draw [overbrace style] (URI.north west) -- (fragment.north east) node [overbrace text style] {URI};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6mm,amplitude=3pt,mirror},color=gray] (schema.south west) -- (fragment.south east) node [font=\tiny, below, pos=.5, yshift=-7mm] {Schema};
    \draw [underbrace style] (fragment.south west) -- (fragment.south east) node [underbrace text style] {Fragment};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will just have to make sure that each place where you need to place the beginning or ending of an underbrace or overbrace is set as its own `node` in its own column of the `matrix`.

Moreover, if you don't want to have to set the options manually for the lower underbrace in the second `tikzpicture`, you could set something like an 'under-underbrace `\tikzstyle`' globally, or something like that.

---

Additionally, you could also wrap the `\draw` commands in a macro. For example, you could put this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{twoopt}
\newcommandtwoopt{\tikzoverbrace}[5][][]{\draw [overbrace style,#1] (#3.north west) -- (#4.north east) node [overbrace text style,#2] {#5};}
\newcommandtwoopt{\tikzunderbrace}[5][][]{\draw [underbrace style,#1] (#3.south west) -- (#4.south east) node [underbrace text style,#2] {#5};}
```

And then you could write:

```
\tikzoverbrace{schema-spezifisch}{fragment}{Schema-Spezifisch}
```

instead of:

```
\draw [overbrace style] (schema-spezifisch.north west) -- (fragment.north east) node [overbrace text style] {Schema-Spezifisch};
```

And you could also write:

```
\tikzunderbrace[][text=orange]{nutzerinfo}{nutzerinfo}{Nutzerinfo}
```

instead of:

```
\draw [underbrace style] (nutzerinfo.south west) -- (nutzerinfo.south east) node [underbrace text style,text=orange] {Nutzerinfo};
```

You'll still have to set the `matrix` independently of these new commands, with this solution, however.

---

**Update:**

As @FrederickNord points out in the comments, adding `nodes={anchor=south}, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex` to the `matrix` style will ensure that the overbraces and underbraces (at least in this particular MWE) are correctly aligned. Another option is to use `\vphantom{...}` inside the `node`s, which is the option used in the MWE above.

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Excellent answer. But somehow the heights seems to differ. If you look closely at the Port portion you will notice that the brace is lower than the Host brace. The effect is very visible when using a different font, i.e. Palatino. Would it be possible to have the braces aligned nicely?

Comment: I found out that adding `nodes={anchor=south}, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex` to the style of the matrix makes it look nice.

Comment: @FrederickNord Yes, I think that should do it. Otherwise, I put some `\vphantom{/}` commands in some of the `node`s, I think, in order to resolve that issue in terms of the alignment for the underbraces of 'port' and 'pfad'. I guess I forgot to do that for all of the `node`s; however, I think your solution is probably better.

Comment: @FrederickNord I updated the MWE so all of the `node`s that need them have `\vphantom{/}` commands inside of them, and I've noted your approach as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution I used when I needed to underbrace text was simple to use math mode wrapped inside a new command:

```
\newcommand{\undertext}[2] {$\underbrace{\textrm{#1}}_{\textrm{#2}}$}
```

Then you just `\undertext{any text}{like this}`