# TikZ Drawing not Fully Showing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not sure what this problem is called so it's hard to search for information... When I use the [`tikz`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) package sometimes part of the drawing does not show fully. Currently the code I am using for a curly brace is not showing its right side... Why?

The [original code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128064/how-to-overbrace-underbrace-in-text-mode-using-tikz) from where I took it had a picture that seemed to display correctly. This is not the first time that this has happened on my Textmate.

[image]

Here is a minimal working code that uses the template I am using and only shows the graph with problematic curling braces: http://pastebin.com/g4j7kKAF

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}    
        \tikzstyle{underbrace style}=[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=10mm,amplitude=5pt,mirror},color=black]    

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        >=stealth,
        shorten >=2pt,
        thick
      ]
        \matrix (block) [%
          matrix of nodes,
          nodes={%
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            minimum width=2em,
            minimum height=1em
          }
        ] {%
          1 & 2 & \node[fill=gray!99]{8}; & \node[fill=gray!50]{3}; & 4 & 6 & 9\\
        };
%\node[fill=gray!50]{1};
        \path[->] (block-1-4.north) edge [bend right=30] (block-1-3.north)
                  (block-1-3.south) edge [bend right=30] (block-1-4.south);
        \draw (block-1-1.west) node[left=0.005cm,scale=0.9] {A:};                              
        \draw (block-1-2.south) node[below=0.1cm] {$\longleftarrow$};                  
        \draw (block-1-2.south) node[left=0.2cm,below=0.4cm,scale=0.6] {Ordenado};                          
        \draw (block-1-1.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {0};
        \draw (block-1-2.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {1};
        \draw (block-1-3.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {i=2};
        \draw (block-1-4.north) node[above=0.05cm,scale=0.7] {j=3};
        \draw (block-1-5.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {4};
        \draw (block-1-6.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {5};
        \draw (block-1-7.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {6};           
        \draw (block-1-2.south east) node[right=0.25cm,below=1.9cm] {$\longrightarrow$};            
        \draw [thin] (block-1-2.south east) +(0,-2) -- +(0,+2);        
        \draw (block-1-2.south east) node[right=0.25cm,below=2.1cm] {Fronteira};    
        \draw [underbrace style] (block-1-1.south west) -- (block-1-2.south east) node [left=0.8cm,below=1.05cm] {$A_{esquerdo}$};                   
        \draw [underbrace style] (block-1-2.south east) -- (block-1-7.south east) node [left=1.8cm,below=1.05cm] {$A_{direito}$};                           

      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that gives trouble?

Comment: @closers: since the question has been asked recently, I would give to the OP the opportunity to add the problematic code before voting to close.

Comment: If you are using `tikzmark` (the `remember picture` option) you will need to compile at least twice. If you are using `tikzmark` without `remember picture` you need to add it since it works only with that option.

Comment: @Claudio The code has been referenced. Any code will give the same problem. I will upload a picture of myself running the code, if you feel it is needed.

Comment: @OeufcoquePenteano: I'm sorry, but you should be more specific than "Any code will give the same problem.". Which code did you use (the question or the answer) and which code did you use to get the picture you posted? There could be a number of reasons why it's not working so to really detect the problem we need: a) the code you used, b) the errors you got. Don't be shy to post your code: anybody has to start somewhere.

Comment: I've included the template and code I am using, and removed all else other than the image. I can't reduce the example any further, as I reused different templates in other to result in the desired looking of lectures notes I desired. I was also unable to post it in Tex Exchange, please do so if you know how. 

I hope this suffices.

Comment: Please, look at what's supposed to be a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is due to `shorten >=2pt` option. It makes all paths `2pt` shorter, so `decorated`  paths are also shorter than expected. Apply `shorten >=0pt` option to `underbrace` style paths and they will be long enough.

I've made some corrections to your code.

1. It's better to use `tikzset` instead to `tikzstyle`: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
2. Don't use `\node` inside a `matrix of nodes`. You can change `node options` with syntax `|[options]|`.

You corrected code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}    
\tikzset{underbrace style/.style = 
{decorate, 
 decoration={brace, raise=10mm, amplitude=5pt, mirror},
 shorten >=0pt, color=black}}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
        >=stealth,
        shorten >=2pt,
        thick
      ]
\matrix (block) [%
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={%
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            minimum width=2em,
            minimum height=1em
      }
      ] 
{%
  1 & 2 & |[fill=gray!99]| 8 & |[fill=gray!50]| 3 & 4 & 6 & 9\\
};

\path[->] (block-1-4.north) edge [bend right=30] 
           (block-1-3.north)
          (block-1-3.south) edge [bend right=30] 
          (block-1-4.south);
\draw (block-1-1.west) node[left=0.005cm,scale=0.9] {A:};                              
\draw (block-1-2.south) node[below=0.1cm] {$\longleftarrow$};                  
\draw (block-1-2.south) node[left=0.2cm,below=0.4cm,scale=0.6] {Ordenado};                          
\draw (block-1-1.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {0};
\draw (block-1-2.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {1};
\draw (block-1-3.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {i=2};
\draw (block-1-4.north) node[above=0.05cm,scale=0.7] {j=3};
\draw (block-1-5.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {4};
\draw (block-1-6.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {5};
\draw (block-1-7.north) node[above=0.1cm,scale=0.7] {6};           
\draw (block-1-2.south east) node[right=0.25cm,below=1.9cm] {$\longrightarrow$};            
\draw [thin] (block-1-2.south east) +(0,-2) -- +(0,+2);        
\draw (block-1-2.south east) node[right=0.25cm,below=2.1cm] {Fronteira};    
\draw [underbrace style] (block-1-1.south west) -- (block-1-2.south east) node [left=0.8cm,below=1.05cm] {$A_{esquerdo}$};                   
\draw [underbrace style] (block-1-2.south east) -- (block-1-7.south east) node [left=1.8cm,below=1.05cm] {$A_{direito}$};                      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]