# Node at tip/pinch of brace in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations

I'm trying to add some explanatory braces in my graphic, and find myself running into some minor difficulties/inconveniences.

**[Edit]:** After being made aware that the main thrust of the question (about off-center tips of braces) is already covered in [How to draw an unbalanced curly brace in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110907/42225), I removed that part. **[\Edit]**

I was wondering if there's a built-in way to determine the position of the tip of the brace from all the given parameters and automatically place a node there. Right now I have to calculate the orthonormal vector to the one which spans the brace, which is tedious, especially for many braces. I tried testing some options from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95144/42225 (which weren't listed in the `PGF` manual), but to no avail.

Also, I think it would be cleaner to have (my implementation of) `underext` as a key in `decoration={...}`; is there a way to set it, e.g. like `decoration/underext/.style={pre=moveto,pre length=#1,post=moveto,post length=#1}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,%
    underext/.style={decoration={pre=moveto,pre length=#1,post=moveto,post length=#1}}]
\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{asin(1/6)}
\clip (-\ang:6) arc (-\ang:90+\ang:6) -- (-1,-1) -- cycle;

\foreach \r / \i [evaluate=\r as \ang using 90/\r] in {8/4} % radius and number of slice
{
\begin{scope}[rotate={(\i-1)*\ang}]
    \foreach \m in {2}
    {
    % Minkowski sum
    \filldraw [fill=black!5,draw=black] ($(-\ang:\r/2)+(-\ang-90:\m)$) arc (-\ang-90:-\ang-180:\m)
    arc (-\ang:\ang:\r/2-\m) arc (\ang+180:\ang+90:\m)
    -- ($(\ang:2*\r)+(\ang+90:\m)$) arc (\ang+90:\ang:\m)
    arc (\ang:-\ang:2*\r+\m) arc (-\ang:-\ang-90:\m) -- cycle;

    % support
    \filldraw[draw=black,fill=black!20] (-\ang:\r/2) arc (-\ang:\ang:\r/2) -- (\ang:2*\r) arc (\ang:-\ang:2*\r) -- cycle;

    % axis of cone
    \draw[very thin] (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (0:\r/2) coordinate (B);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt,raise=3pt,aspect=0.6},underext=1.5pt,very thin] (A)--(B);
    \coordinate (base) at ($(A)!0.6!(B)$);
    \coordinate (ortho) at ($(0,0)!1!90:($(B)-(A)$)$);
    \node[inner sep=2pt] at ($(base)!-15pt!($(base)+(ortho)$)$) {$2^{j-1}$};
    };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[very thin,<->]
    \draw (-1,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (0,6);
\end{scope}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whereas what I'd like to have would be something along the lines of:

```
\draw[very thin] (0,0) node[shape=coordinate](A){} -- (0:\r/2) node[shape=coordinate](B){};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt,raise=3pt,aspect=0.6,underext=1.5pt,
    node at tip=node name},very thin] (A)--(B);
\node[below=2pt] at (node name) {$2^{j-1}$};
```

Comment: Duplicate ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/how-to-draw-an-unbalanced-curly-brace-in-tikz

Comment: @percusse: Ok thanks, I searched before I asked, but didn't find this. I'll edit the question to be about the automatic node creation.

Comment: Why is `\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt,raise=3pt,aspect=0.6},underext=1.5pt,very thin] (A) -- node[below=2pt] {$2^{j-1}$} (B);` not good enough?

Comment: @Turion: Maybe I misunderstand something, but running your suggestion places the node in such a way that it intersects both the brace and the border of the light grey area. The goal is to have to the tip of the brace point to the node. I could use `node[near end,...]` or `pos=0.6`, but `below=x pt` will not (really) help me move orthogonally to the brace. Of course I can play around with the values until it almost fits, but the question was about an automatic placement...

Comment: `below right` with a bigger distance should do it, I can fiddle around with it when I'm home. The only other way I can think of would be looking into the code of the decoration and monkey patching it.

Comment: @Turion: Thanks for the offer - I know `below right` as well, but (together with the other 7 axial and diagonal directions) that still only approximates the vector orthogonal to the brace up to an angle of `pi/8=22.5deg`. I guess you could argue this is enough (together with the freedom of `pos=...`), but my point is that I don't want to fine-tune so many parameters for many braces (especially if I decide to change the rotation parameter later on).

What I imagine should calculate the position given all relevant parameters (`raise`, `amplitude`, etc.).

Comment: If you're fine with turning the direction of the text, you can use `sloped`, I think.

Comment: @Turion: This doesn't change the position, it just rotates the text to match the slope of the line. Also, due to the scope with the rotation, I'd have to use `transform shape`, which (undesirably) then also takes `scale=...` into account.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I think it would be cleaner to have (my implementation of) `underext` as a key in `decoration={...}`; is there a way to set it, e.g. like `decoration/underext/.style={pre=moveto,pre length=#1,post=moveto,post length=#1}`?

Almost, since the whole `decoration` stuff is done by PGF, the keys are actually in the `/pgf` namespace.
Thus, you need to do either

```
\pgfset{decoration/underext/.style={…}}
```

or

```
\tikzset{/pgf/decoration/underext/.style={…}}
```

---

This answer provides two new `auto` function:

- `left with offset` and
- `right with offset`

There work like `left` and `right` but they push the node (or coordinate) orthogonally to the side about the length of `/tikz/auto offset`.
Remember that these snap to the eight compass anchors.

This value key is initialized with value of the amplitude and the raise value.

There's a lot of similar calculations done but it was the only way for me to differentiate between sloped and not-sloped nodes. Transformations are all over the place and very confusing!

If you would `draw` the nodes, you'd see that they touch just the tip:
[image]

---

The `every brace node` style sets up the appropriate `auto` function and the right `pos`ition.

For the `sloped` example, I'm using the same path outside of your rotated `scope` because otherwise [it'll be weird](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458037/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfset{decoration/raise/.append code=% Ugh!
  \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/decoration/raise}{#1}}%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/decoration/raise}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665784/16595
  swap/.style={swap auto/.expand once=\tikz@auto@anchor@direction},
  swap auto/.is choice,
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1=#2}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfutil@namedef{tikz@install@auto@anchor@#1}{%
                \let\tikz@do@auto@anchor\tikz@auto@anchor@on
                \def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{#1}},
    swap auto/#1/.code=\def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{#2}},
  /utils/temp/.list={left=right, right=left,
    left with offset=right with offset, right with offset=left with offset},
  % which side → mirror/reverse path → auto
  % where      → reverse path/aspect → pos
  every brace node/.style={
    auto=% Ugh?
      \ifx\tikz@dec@mirror\relax
        \ifpgf@decorate@inputsegmentobjects@reverse right\else left\fi
      \else
        \ifpgf@decorate@inputsegmentobjects@reverse left\else right\fi
      \fi\space with offset,
    pos=\ifpgf@decorate@inputsegmentobjects@reverse
          1-\fi(\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect)},
  auto offset/.initial=% doesn't need to be used with decoration,
                       % can just be a fixed distance
    \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/raise})}
\pgfutil@namedef{tikz@auto@anchor@left with offset}{%
  \tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor
  \xdef\tikz@marshal{%
      \pgf@process{%
        \noexpand\pgftransformreset
        \noexpand\pgftransformrotate{+90}%
        \noexpand\pgfpointtransformed{%
          \noexpand\pgfpointscale{\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/auto offset}}
                                 {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}}}%
      \advance\pgf@pt@x\pgf@x
      \advance\pgf@pt@y\pgf@y}%
  \tikz@auto@post
  \ifpgfslopedattime
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{%
      \pgftransformreset
      \pgftransformrotate{90}%
      \pgfpointtransformed{%
        \pgf@process{%
          \tikz@timer%
          \pgf@x=\pgf@pt@aa pt
          \pgf@y=\pgf@pt@ab pt
          \pgfpointnormalised{}%
          \pgfpointscale{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/auto offset}}{}}}}%
    \advance\pgf@pt@x\pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@pt@y\pgf@y
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xb
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yb
  \else
    \tikz@marshal
  \fi}
\pgfutil@namedef{tikz@auto@anchor@right with offset}{%
  \tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor@prime
  \xdef\tikz@marshal{%
    \pgf@process{%
      \noexpand\pgftransformreset
      \noexpand\pgftransformrotate{-90}%
      \noexpand\pgfpointtransformed{%
        \noexpand\pgfpointscale{\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/auto offset}}
                               {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}}}%
    \advance\pgf@pt@x\pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@pt@y\pgf@y}%
  \tikz@auto@post
  \ifpgfslopedattime
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{%
      \pgftransformreset
      \pgftransformrotate{-90}%
      \pgfpointtransformed{%
        \pgf@process{%
          \tikz@timer%
          \pgf@x=\pgf@pt@aa pt
          \pgf@y=\pgf@pt@ab pt
          \pgfpointnormalised{}%
          \pgfpointscale{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/auto offset}}{}}}}%
    \advance\pgf@pt@x\pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@pt@y\pgf@y
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xb
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yb
  \else
    \tikz@marshal
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=1.5,
  /pgf/decoration/underext/.style={
    pre=moveto, pre length={#1}, post=moveto, post length={#1}}]
\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{asin(1/6)}
\clip (-\ang:6) arc [start angle=-\ang, end angle=90+\ang, radius=6] -- (-1,-1) -- cycle;

\foreach \r / \i [evaluate=\r as \ang using 90/\r] in {8/4}{ % radius and number of slice
  \begin{scope}[rotate={(\i-1)*\ang}]
  \foreach \m in {2}{
    % Minkowski sum
    \filldraw [fill=black!5, draw=black, delta angle=-90, radius=\m]
      ($(-\ang:\r/2)+(-\ang-90:\m)$)
      arc [start angle=-\ang-90]
      arc [start angle=-\ang, end angle=\ang, radius=\r/2-\m]
      arc [start angle=\ang+180]
      -- ($(\ang:2*\r)+(\ang+90:\m)$)
      arc [start angle=\ang+90]
      arc [start angle=\ang, end angle=-\ang, radius=2*\r+\m]
      arc [start angle=-\ang] -- cycle;

    % support
    \filldraw[draw=black,fill=black!20]
      (-\ang:\r/2)
      arc [start angle=-\ang, end angle=\ang, radius=\r/2] coordinate[midway] (B)
      -- (\ang:2*\r)
      arc [start angle=\ang, end angle=-\ang, radius=2*\r] -- cycle;

    % axis of cone
    \draw[very thin] (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (B);
    \draw[
      decorate,
      decoration={
        brace, mirror,
        amplitude=10pt, raise=3pt, aspect=0.6
      },
      very thin] (A)-- node[every brace node]{$2^{j-1}$} (B);
    \coordinate (base) at ($(A)!0.6!(B)$);
    \coordinate (ortho) at ($(0,0)!1!90:($(B)-(A)$)$);
    \node[inner sep=2pt,gray] at ($(base)!-15pt!($(base)+(ortho)$)$) {$2^{j-1}$};
  }
  \end{scope}
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, reverse path, mirror,
    amplitude=10pt, raise=3pt, aspect=0.6}, very thin]
    (A)-- node[every brace node,sloped]{$2^{j-1}$} (B);
}
\path[very thin, <->] (-1,0) edge (6,0) (0,-1) edge (0,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is very cool, thanks a lot! :) The code and how it works is kinda inscrutable for me now, would be cool if this could eventually make its way into pgf. But yeah, my LaTeX days are a while behind me now, haha.