# making an arrow with text layer over a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a code that looks something like the following, where I have arrows with text crossing over a dashed line from a rectangle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   
    \draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];

    \node (A) at (-1, 0) {A};
    
   \node (B) at (1, 0) {B};

    \draw [->] (-0.8, 0.1) -- (0.8, 0.1) node[above, midway] {text1};
    \draw [->] (0.8, -.1) -- (-0.8, -.1) node[below, midway] {text2};
 

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The output of my code looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have the diagram arranged such that the text is layered over the rectangle. I did find that using `fill opacity` option for the text can fill over the rectangle, however for longer texts this also cuts out the arrow when it fills over the text, which I want to avoid:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could point me towards making an arrow with text that can just cover over the rectangle, but does not interfere with covering over other arrows/texts.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `fill=white` in your nodes.
For better positioning the text, you can use `yshift`.
Off-topic: you can also use `shift` to position the arrows with respect to the nodes, instead of using absolute coordinate values.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} non more needed

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mylabel/.style={midway, fill=white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
    
    \node (A) at (-1, 0) {A};
    
    \node (B) at (1, 0) {B};
    
    \draw [->] (-0.8, 0.1) -- (0.8, 0.1) node[above, mylabel, yshift=.3mm] {text1};
    \draw [->] (0.8, -.1) -- (-0.8, -.1) node[below, mylabel, yshift=-.3mm] {text2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
    
    \node (A) at (-1, 0) {A};
    
    \node (B) at (1, 0) {B};
    
    \draw [->] ([shift={(-.5mm,.1cm)}]A.east) -- ([shift={(.5mm,.1cm)}]B.west) node[above, mylabel, yshift=.3mm] {text1};
    \draw [->] ([shift={(.5mm,-.1cm)}]B.west) -- ([shift={(-.5mm,-.1cm)}]A.east) node[below, mylabel, yshift=-.3mm] {text2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
    
    \node (A) at (-1, 0) {A};
    
    \node (B) at (1, 0) {B};
    
    \draw [->] (-0.8, 0.1) -- (0.8, 0.1) node[above, mylabel, yshift=1mm] {long text text1};
    \draw [->] (0.8, -.1) -- (-0.8, -.1) node[below, mylabel, yshift=-1mm] {long text text2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
    
    \node (A) at (-1, 0) {A};
    
    \node (B) at (1, 0) {B};
    
    \draw [->] ([shift={(-.5mm,.1cm)}]A.east) -- ([shift={(.5mm,.1cm)}]B.west) node[above, mylabel, yshift=1mm] {long text text1};
    \draw [->] ([shift={(.5mm,-.1cm)}]B.west) -- ([shift={(-.5mm,-.1cm)}]A.east) node[below, mylabel, yshift=-1mm] {long text text2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`behind path` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/behind:path) so that the nodes along the arrows are put behind the arrows but that won't help with them covering the previous nodes `A` and `B`.

I suggest using a non-zero `outer sep`.
This however will mean that a line drawn to those nodes in the future will not touch the nodes but stop a bit before. A more sophisticated solution is possible by using [`auto = left with offset`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676289/16595) but if you don't have to reference the nodes, using `outer sep` is much more straight-forward.

Using the height of a capital letter (i.e. one of those in the connected nodes) we could evaluate the exact value that is needed so that the node *just* doesn't cover the text but the calculation aren't that straight forward because sometimes the glyphs are bigger than their reported height. (This is why I'm using `-.8mm` instead of `-1mm`. You can always just use any length here to just eyeball it.)

I've also used TikZ-CD's `shift left` key to draw these parallel lines without having to manually find the proper starting points. (This works best with orthongal lines and non-drawned nodes.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzset{cd/.code=\tikzcdset{#1}}
\begin{document}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
\node (A) at (-1, 0) {A}; \node (B) at ( 1, 0) {B};

\path[->, cd={shift left=1mm}, auto=left, nodes={fill=white}]
  (A) edge node {text1} (B)
  (B) edge node {text2} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
\node (A) at (-1, 0) {A}; \node (B) at ( 1, 0) {B};

\path[->, cd={shift left=1mm}, auto=left, nodes={fill=white, behind path}]
  (A) edge node {longer text, only \texttt{behind path}} (B)
  (B) edge node {also covers other text}                 (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) rectangle (2,-1) [dashed];
\node (A) at (-1, 0) {A}; \node (B) at ( 1, 0) {B};

\path[->, cd={shift left=1mm}, auto=left,
      nodes={fill=white, behind path, outer sep=.5*height("A")-.8mm}]
  (A) edge node {longer text}            (B)
  (B) edge node {also covers other text} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

Here is the output with `fill = yellow` to highlight where the actual node lies.

[image]